# Getting a list of branches that were merged into another branch

Tags: git, branch

I'm having some trouble doing this in a non convoluted way... currently I can figure out which branches were merged into a branch by outputting branches --merged from the target branch and from master, writing the output from those commands to files, and then diffing those two files. Does anyone have a better way to get this info?

For example, say branches branch1, branch2, and branch3 are all cut from master and dev work is done on them. Then, branch1 and branch2 are merged into integrationBranch. The command should be able to tell me that branch1 and branch2 were merged into integrationBranch.

EDIT:

When I run git branch --merged, the branch that's merged in first is always dropped from the output.

Example:

```
git checkout inegraionBranch
git merge origin/branch1
git merge origin/branch2

git branch merged
*integrationBranch
branch2
```

Comment: Why not just checkout `integrationBranch` and then do `git branch --merged`?

Comment: Really good point. I think I can leverage this to do what I need to do. Thanks.

Comment: @Uroc327: you don't even have to check it out: `git branch --merged` takes an optional commit-ID.  That commit-ID merely *defaults* to `HEAD` (note, the argument is effectively run through `git rev-parse`; try `git rev-parse HEAD` and `git rev-parse integrationBranch`).

Comment: Actually, I noticed that git branch --merged is always leaving out the first branch that was merged into a release branch. Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the case of your example you'll want to use `git branch -a --merged integrationBranch`

The two branches `origin/branch1` and `origin/branch2` are remote branches and aren't listed with `git branch` by default so neither is showing up in your output unless you use a `-a` switch.

I'm guessing the reason you are seeing `branch2` is that you probably have a local branch named `branch2` which is merged in (ie, the problem is not that the command is dropping the first branch)

EDIT:

To get all of the branches merged into `integrationBranch` but not into `master` you could do:

```
git branch --list -a --merged integrationBranch | sed 's/^..//;s/ .*//' | xargs git branch --list -a --no-merged master
```

Comment: This returns a list of all branches that were merged into master even when I specify integrationBranch. For example, git branch -a --merged | wc -l returns 5k some branches, and git branch -a --merged integrationBranch | wc -l also returns 5k some branches

Comment: nm, the branch counts just happened to be identical with the test branch I was using. this works, but to filter the output down to a reasonable list, I need to do what I was originally doing... write an output of merged branches to master to a file, write the output of the branches merged into my integrationBranch, and diff to two to get the difference.

Comment: Ahh - wasn't clear to me from your example that you wanted to diff it against the branches which were merged into `master` already.  I've edited the answer above with an example which could help you get that without writing temporary files to disk.  Does it solve your issue?

Comment: Getting this error: error: unknown switch `>'. I've tried using 's/^..//' to remove the first 2 blank spaces in the output of git branch, and have also tried removing remotes/origin/ and just getting the branch name as well. Still getting the error.

Comment: I should've tested my first attempt with a repo that had remotes.  I've updated the answer above to include a `'s/ .*//'` to remove the " -> origin/master" output that you'll get for remote refs (and which was causing the `unknown switch` message you saw).

Comment: Hmmm... the output after the sed is looking better, but when I try just one line from that output with 'git branch -a --no-merged master <branch_name>', I get an error that says 'git branch' does not make sense with a branch name. example of a branch outputted by git branch -a --merged integrationBranch | sed 's/^..//;s/ .*//' would be something like remotes/origin/branch1, and when I run git branch -a --no-merged master branch1, I get the error "fatal: -a and -r options to 'git branch' do not make sense with a branch name". Thanks for all the help btw.

Comment: hmm... maybe we're using different git versions?  mine is 1.8.3.4

Comment: if you add a `--list` to the second (or both) git branch commands, does that get rid of the fatal message?

Comment: I'm running 1.7.9.5. Adding list worked! This is much better, thank you. If only I could tell it to go "one level deep" now... so I would only see the first level of children from the integrationBranch if you thought of it as a tree. Seriously, thanks for the help here.

Comment: No problem!  Not sure I understand the second part though